# How to convert non english characters into Unicode (UTF-8)

Tags: pdf, unicode, utf-8, fonts

I am trying to copy articles from newspaper.
Below is the sample screenshot of the text from the pdf format

[image: Bengali text]

when I copy it from the pdf format of the newspaper, and paste it on either microsoft word or excel, it gives the following characters:

·Æ°·C≥

I believe the font is **shree bangala font**. (not 100% sure)

I have seen other font like **Nirmala font** which I didn't face issue while working in the utf-8 encoding.

It would be very helpful if someone could guide me how to convert the above text.

Comment: I'm not sure this has anything to do with the font. In PDF, there are many ways to represent text, and some of them might make it very hard to extract them automatically. (In extreme cases, doing OCR is the easiest solution..) I suggest you add the `pdf` tag and be prepared to dig into the details of the PDF format. You can probably delete the `java` tag; I don't see why it should be relevant.

Comment: Most likely the font (at least as it is embedded in the pdf) does not contain the information (or even contains false information) for text extraction. Without the pdf this is pure guesswork,  though.